# Transfer Excel row data into its relevant columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've lost days to this problem.

To solve this issue I have amassed 6 sheets of different data with different attempts. I've tried offsets, dynamic ranges, vlookups, counts, countifs, left, right, row, everything. I can't get around it.

What I want to do is transpose data in the following format:
[image: in the following format:]

Into its correspondingly named four columns to reach the desired outcome:

[image: outcome]

Inconsistency of each individual product's data is the issue. Product 9 has two product options and two prices, whilst the tenth product has no description and no options.

I also have the original data in the following format if it is of use.

[image: following format]

Any help or resources greatly appreciated.

I have gotten by with excel for the past few years without learning VBA, therefore a formula approach is most welcome. Though, if necessary, I am not massively intimidated by learning the language if needs be as I am a novice in CSS and HTML and dabbled in a couple of programming languages.

Edit 1 - A more concise way of viewing the issue [is contained in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOJv6.png) where the data is on the left and the outcome is on the right.

Edit 2 - [This is a link to a google sheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FemyCKtdXND2qUnVFK7oY0GvFQbV67qy) subject to request in the comments below. I have included all relevant information and some other stuff.

Comment: Power query seems like a good fit to solve these problems. what excel version do you have?

Comment: If your data structure was strictly formatted so that every product # had the same four types in the same order, it would be fairly simple to achieve with OFFSET. Perhaps it is possible to get it into that format with one of your other solutions, then apply the OFFSET approach

Comment: excel vba can be used with original data to solve it.if you want i can code it send me original data file

Comment: @bob_1982 This is not how Stack Overflow works. All the relevant code has to be in the question and the answer **itself**. This is no free code writing service. Refer to [ask], [answer] and [help].

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I never knew Power query was a thing. Will investigate. Thanks!

Comment: @Samantha I have updated/edited the question highlighting that the data doesn't always follow the same order, thus invalidating this approach. Of course that would be the dream but thanks!

Comment: Your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. OCR programs usually don't work well. That or manually entry is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have included a link to a google sheet subject to your request. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: you've added clarification since I put this together. I'll leave it in, because it is a partial solution and may lead you/someone to a full one.
(it supplies only 1 result if there are multiple matches for a particular product and information type, but handles missing information).

I have a solution. In your second example of the input (product #, type and information columns across the top), insert a new column between B and C. In the first data row of that new column, combine the text from the product # and 'Type' columns, i.e

```
C2 = A2 & "," & B2
```

Result of C2 should be "Product 1,Product Name"

Then for your transposed results table, all you need is a valid list of product #'s, and you can use a simple vlookup on C and D columns. You just have to construct a matching search term that combines the required product # with the type you are looking for.

[image]

The formula in H2 below is constructed so that you can drag it across and down as necessary.

You'll get N/A for anything that doesn't have an entry, and you'll get whatever vlookup usually does if it finds duplicate matches.